# parse the specific string into desired output

Tags: java, regex

I have 2 case as mention in main method.

***In case 1 *** match method is returning the exactly what i want but

***In case 2*** its returning empty list.

please help me to give a common regex which can work in both cases.
examples input string:

```
"\"NB_DAY_DIM\".\"MONTH_YEAR\"+\"l\".\"m\""
```

desired o/p:

[{column=MONTH_YEAR, value="NB_DAY_DIM"."MONTH_YEAR", table=NB_DAY_DIM},{column=m, value="l"."m", table=l}]

```
public static List<Map<String, String>> match(String source) {
String pattern = "\"(.*?)\".\"(.*?)\"";


    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(source);

    while (m.find()) {

        Map<String, String> mp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mp.put("value", m.group(0));
        mp.put("table", m.group(1));
        mp.put("column", m.group(2));

        list.add(mp);
        source = source.replace(m.group(0), "");
        m = r.matcher(source);
    }

    return list;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(match("\"NB_DAY_DIM\".\"MONTH_YEAR\"+\"l\".\"m\""));//case 1
    System.out.println(match("NB_DAY_DIM.MONTH_YEAR+l.m"));//case 2
}
```

operator between `NB_DAY_DIM.MONTH_YEAR` and `l.m` can be arithmetic or logical operator like `"NB_DAY_DIM.MONTH_YEAR-l.m"` 
it can also have repetitive pattern like `NB_DAY_DIM.MONTH_YEAR+l.m-xyz.abc*l.m`

Comment: It's hard to read your question/initial text. Can you reformat and add punctuation?

Comment: Are the quotation marks completely optional or are only those two cases allowed? What I mean is, should input like `NB_DAY_DIM"."MONTH_YEAR+"l.m"` match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the quotation marks are completely optional, try this expression (non-Java notation):

```
"?([^+"]+)"?\."?([^+"]+)"?
```

A short breakdown:

- `"?` means optional quotation marks
- `([^+"]+)` means a sequence of at least one character which is not a plus or quotation mark
- Thus the complete expression means "two sequences of at least one character which are not a plus or quotation mark, separated by a dot and surrounded by optional quotation marks.

**Update:**

Here's an expression for "either all quotation marks or none":

```
(?<=\+|^)("?)([^+"]+)\1\.\1([^+"]+)\1(?:\+|$)
```

The changes are:

- group 1 is now the quotation mark, thus you'd have to change your code which reads the qroups
- `\1` is a back reference to group one, i.e. if the first quotation mark is found, all others have to be there as well, if not, no quotation mark would be allowed.
- `(?=\+|$)` is used to define that a match must be followed by either a plus or the end of input. This is needed to reject cases which only have trailing quotation marks, e.g. `NB_DAY_DIM.MONTH_YEAR"`
- likewise `(?<=\+|^)` is used to prevent cases which only have leading quotation marks, e.g. `"NB_DAY_DIM.MONTH_YEAR+l.m`

This expression would match

- `NB_DAY_DIM.MONTH_YEAR+"l"."m"`
- `"NB_DAY_DIM"."MONTH_YEAR"+"l"."m"`
- `NB_DAY_DIM.MONTH_YEAR+l.m`
- etc.

but not

- `"NB_DAY_DIM.MONTH_YEAR+"l"."m"`
- `NB_DAY_DIM."MONTH_YEAR"+"l"."m"`
- `NB_DAY_DIM.MONTH_YEAR"+l.m`
- etc.

**Update 2:** since the comment says the delimiter could be any arithmetical operator, just expand the disallowed characters to inlcude them, e.g. instead of `[^+"]` use `[^+\-*/"]`. Additionally expand the look-behind/look-ahead from `\+|^` to `[+\-*/]|^`.

Here's an expanded expression, if there are additional requirements, feel free to add them:

```
(?<=[+\-*/]|^)("?)([^+\-*/"]+)\1\.\1([^+\-*/"]+)\1(?=[+\-*/]|$)
```

This would match `NB_DAY_DIM.MONTH_YEAR+l.m-xyz.abc*l.m`.

**Update 3:**

In order to extract `<table>.<column>` pairs from your string, you can use an expression like this:

```
"?(\w+)"?\."?(\w+)"?
```

Note that this doesn't ensure that either all quotes are set or none and it also assumes you're only using word characters (i.e. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) for table and column names.

It might serve your purpose, however.

If you need additional help, please start a new question and don't put it all into this one. I'd advise to dive into regex syntax (a good source would be http://regular-epxressions.info), if you need it more often (and it's always good to know).

A last note on regular expressions: not all problems are best solved (or even solvable) with regex. Your examples are starting to get more and more complicated and it seems you're actually attempting to write some parser. Regex are of limited use here.

Comment: @Shekhar it would be nice to include that in your post, since if the requirements are not clear the answers can't be either.

Comment: I don't need to handle those case where double quote is open and not close. All the inputs will be valid.

Comment: i am not getting any value in  m.group(1).

Comment: @Shekhar which regex are you using? Did you read my comments? If you use one of the latter ones, your groups would have other numbers, e.g. 0, 2 and 3 (since group 1 is the first quote).

Comment: thanks.it's working fine for all my cases.can you tell me if "\"NB_DAY_DIM\".\"MONTH_YEAR\"-abs(\"l\".\"m\")"  or "NB_DAY_DIM.MONTH_YEAR*add(l.m)" then what i have to do?

Comment: @Shekhar you could also change the expression to match two character sequences divided by a dot. I'll add an update if I have the time.